# "Little improvement" vs. "Little improvements"?

Tags: idioms, grammatical-number

If the term *Little improvement* refers to the stagnance of progress, and *Little improvements* refer to a number of small additions, what is the plural of many stagnances of progress?

As in, "You have very little improvement. All of you have __ __!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because *little improvement*, with no article, is an uncountable mass noun, it has no plural and stays the same when shared by several people:

> Caesar and Pompeius have shown **little improvement**.

It is similar to other abstract words, like *love* and *compassion*:

> Cleopatra and Agrippina had *little compassion* for those who could use it.
>
> But they gave *much love* to those they could use.

Answer (score 3):

In your first example, *improvement* is not some countable thing.  So if a lot of people each show *little improvement*, then collectively they all show *little improvement*.  (Also note that in that sense of improvement, you normally show, exhibit, or achieve it; rather than have it.)

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is a trick question, "None of you have any improvement"?